# How to read() from clients and a FIFO using select() in C

Tags: c, sockets, select, mkfifo

I `read()` from clients connected to the server, and at the same time, I let `select()` be aware of data coming from a FIFO. Right now, when data is written to the FIFO, selects writes all data to the clients but keeps returning as if it was "ready-to-read". So the next read is set to `-1` and `errno == EAGAIN`. It does this until it reaches fdmax. It works okay though.

But, why do I keep getting `EAGAIN`? and is there a better way to handle this? or is this the proper way?

Note: I'm passing `O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK` so it can also keep `read()`ing data sent by clients and not just the FIFO.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define PORT "9034"
int main(void) {
    fd_set master, read_fds;
    int fdmax, listener, newfd, sbytes, yes=1, i, j, rv; 
    struct sockaddr_storage remoteaddr; // client address
    socklen_t addrlen;
    char buf[256] = {0}, remoteIP[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    struct addrinfo hints, *ai;

    FD_ZERO(&master);
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    int fifo;
    if ((mkfifo("/tmp/fifo", 0666)) < 0)
        perror(strerror(errno));
    if ((fifo = open("/tmp/fifo", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)) < 0)  
        perror(strerror(errno));

    // get us a socket and bind it
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &ai);
    listener = socket(ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, ai->ai_protocol);
    setsockopt(listener, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int));
    bind(listener, ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen);
    freeaddrinfo(ai);
    listen(listener, 10);

    FD_SET (fifo, &master);
    FD_SET(listener, &master);
    fdmax = listener;
    for (;;) {
        read_fds = master;
        if (select(fdmax + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) exit(4);

        for (i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++) {
            if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)) {
                if (i == listener) {
                    addrlen = sizeof remoteaddr;
                    newfd = accept(listener, (struct sockaddr * ) & remoteaddr, & addrlen);
                    FD_SET(newfd, & master);
                    if (newfd > fdmax)
                        fdmax = newfd;
                } else if (i != fifo) {
                    recv(i, buf, sizeof buf, 0); 
                }   
            }
            if (FD_ISSET(fifo, &read_fds)) {
                sbytes = read (fifo, buf, sizeof (buf));
                if (sbytes == -1 && errno == EAGAIN)
                    continue;
                for(j = 0; j <= fdmax; j++) {
                    // send to everyone!
                    if (FD_ISSET(j, &master)) {
                        if (j != listener && j != i && j != fifo) {
                            if (send(j, buf, sbytes, 0) == -1) {
                                perror("send");
                            }   
                        }   
                    }   
                }   
            }   
        }   
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fdmax = listener;` is dubious. You should actually evaluate which is the greater. You need to check the result of each `recv()`. You're not doing that in the socket case. Specifically, it could be zero, which means the peer has disconnected and you should close the socket and remove it from `read_fds` and `master`.

Comment: Thanks. For  simplicity, I removed a lot of the checks. I'll make sure to do add it though.

Comment: as for `fdmax`, if it helps, you can have a look at [this piece of code](https://github.com/boazsegev/c-server-tools/blob/b27548898dea4b0e8fb42b439dd7f50d7c0e7073/src/lib-server.c#L1729-L1749) that checks the maximum file limit for the process (as well as tries to maximize it up to the OS's hard limit).

Comment: @Myst thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++) {
```

Here you are iterating the `read_fds`.

```
if (FD_ISSET(fifo, &read_fds)) {
```

Here you are testing whether `fifo` is readable. Every time around the loop. The first time, you read something, and send it; the next time around the loop, nothing has happened to the FIFO, but the condition above still holds, so you read again and get `EAGAIN`.

This `if` block should be outside and below the loop.

Comment: I understand now and it totally solved the issue. Thanks!